# Finite order of an element in Brauer group.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I know that $A$ is an central simple álgebra over a field $F$, then $[A]$ has finite order in the Brauer group. But, how to prove it?

I appreciate any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It corresponds to a cohomology class in $H^2(G,K^*)$
for some finite Galois extension $K/F$ with Galois group $G$.
Cohomology groups with respect to
 a finite group $G$ are (except for $H^0$)
annihilated by $|G|$.